# how to open QuickReport in msWord

Tags: delphi, report, quickreports

I’m using Delphi 6 and I need to enable the user to modify a Quick report with WinWord.

How can I export whatever chosen to the quick report to word file ?
Or is there any other way to build reports and export them other than quickreport?

Like third part tools?

thank you

Comment: Hi Amanda, was the *QRDesign* what you were looking for ? Or were you asking more to *How to export QuickReport report to MS Word ?* Surely you can export the report output, but the report definition, the *.qrp* file cannot be modified in MS Word, there's no support for them in Word. I understood your question like you want to let your users create or modify existing reports without having *QuickReport* installed and that's what is the *QRDesign* for. Could you leave here some feedback ?

Comment: I want user when they open the quickreport to be able to export it to word so that they can change the header or add another statement

Comment: Then, the `QuickRep1.ExportToFilter(TQRAsciiExportFilter.Create('d:\File.doc'));` might be what you are looking for. It exports the report into a `*.doc` file, that can be modified and printed out like any other `*.doc` file. But if you want let customers build (or modify) their own reports, then you need the `QRDesign`.

Comment: So, was the `ExportToFilter` what you were looking for ? Or try to describe more specific your needs. From the question and your last comment I feel like you need `QRDesign`. But I would appreciate some feedback from you. Thanks!

Comment: thank you TLama for ExportTofilter, but when I tried it,  it gave an error "TQRAsciiExportFilter" undecleared identifier. please help

Answer (score 4):

You were probably looking for the [`QR Design`](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/WebInfoPage.aspx?WebInfoID=646). It is the standalone end-user report designer based on Quickreport. You can either compile it into your application or just distribute it as a standalone, separate application for printing and designing Quickreport reports. For more information about how to get a copy for your Quickreport version [`contact vendor`](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/Contact.aspx).

- [`QRDesign Screenshots`](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/WebInfoPage.aspx?WebInfoID=697)
- [`QRDesign Feature List`](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/WebInfoPage.aspx?WebInfoID=708)

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds (and wrote a better answer). :) +1.